# Odoo 9.0c How can i remove the default value affect of old function?

Tags: default, odoo-9, many-to-one

I have set the value default=1 for my many2one fields, now I would like to remove it or replace by an other  function, however the affect seem maintain when the value still be set. Could you guy please explain to me what is happening with the field, and why even I try to create the new database the function still keep working? Thank for your time.

Answer (score 0):

if you change anything in the python you need to restard the server if nothing is happened then you didn't upgrade your module correctly and if you want to cancel the default value in the first database you cannot just remove it from the code but set it to False  `default = False` this is the default value for every field if you change it then you need to return it by `default = False` because this information is stored in the database in ir.fields

Comment: I have tried to add the default = False, then restart the server and upgrade the module, but nothing hapend, the value still keep setting automatically, do you think that because i have more than one database in one instance?

Comment: to make sure change the default value to some thing else if nothing is happen check the context of the action if there is no 'default_field' in the context then some thing is wrong here only way to define a default is by defaul key word or in the context of the action that open the form